# Returning promise instead of jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have a function that is expected to call jquery.ajax, and return it as a promise for further processing.

But, sometimes, it has enough information to proceed synchronously, without the ajax call. It still needs to return a promise, to fulfill its contract with callers. What is an idiomatic way to do this?

E.g.

```
function f(x) {
  return x? 
    $.ajax({url: "http://myServer", data: x, ...})
    : /* what should be here? */;
}
```

Comment: did you tried with `Promise.resolve()`

Comment: What should the promise be fulfilled with? Where does that data come from?

Comment: The data is available locally. For the sake of this simple example, it can be {}.

jQuery.when({}) seems to do what I want, and is nice and brief.

new Promise.resolve(...) felt too heavy (syntactically), whichi is why I asked this question

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb: It's `Promise.resolve({})` (no `new`), which is just as light as jQuery's `when` but uses proper promises :-)

Comment: Thanks. Which is considered more idiomatic or readable (in code that uses jQuery already)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a fulfilled jQuery promise, you can use [`jQuery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
return $.when(…);
```

To create a rejected jQuery promise, you'll need to use something a bit more complicated (but at least you can chain it):

```
return $.Deferrred().reject(new Error(…)).promise();
```

Comment: Is $.when considered more "proper" (readable, idiomatic, etc.) then Promise.resolve(...)?

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb: No, it just does something different - it returns a jQuery promise instead of a proper ES6 `Promise`. So if you're using jQuery, you should use `$.when`.